Script crashes after multiple different SQLite queries
For a PyQt6 application with an sqlite3 database for my board game collection I created buttons to sort, filter, add and edit. However, if I have already done any other than adding a game, the script crashes if I try to do another. For example if I sort after filtering, the script crashes.




MainWindow inherits from QMainWindow. This class has a method load data:
connection = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
result = connection.execute("SELECT * FROM my_games")
self.table.setRowCount(0)
for row_number, row_data in enumerate(result):
    self.table.insertRow(row_number)
    for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
        self.table.setItem(row_number, column_number, QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
connection.close()

MainWindow has static methods to search, edit, delete, sort and filter. All follow the same design:
@staticmethod
    def filter(self):
        dialog = FilterDialog()
        dialog.exec()

Each references a class such as FilterDialog() which inherits from QDialog. I am using __init__ to create the layout for the dialog box then an additional method performs the action I want and updates MainWindow view. filter_game method of FilterDialog() class:
connection = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()

if id_text:
    result = cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM my_games WHERE ID {id_box_text} {id_text}")
elif duration_text:
    result = cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM my_games WHERE Time {duration_box_text} {duration_text}")
elif released_text:
    result = cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM my_games WHERE Released {released_box_text} {released_text}")

main_window.table.setRowCount(0)
for row_number, row_data in enumerate(result):
    main_window.table.insertRow(row_number)
    for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
        main_window.table.setItem(row_number, column_number, QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
connection.close()

All methods function as expected if just one is ran. Running a different method after that will crash the program. I think because sorting and filtering through SELECT statements doesn't change the database and when I make a connection again there is a mismatch between database and MainWindow view.
A view doesn't seem would get around this. Maybe keeping the connection open would, but may have issues referencing MainWindow. Easiest would be to filter and sort in one class, but I prefer these separate. Would it be better to remove load data method from the MainWindow class and have it as its own separate class and method that is referenced once at the beginning?

Don't guess: make sure. Give the [mcve] article a read, and then start reducing your code to find out at what point repeating your steps no longer produces the problem. Then back up one step.

Also, Qt provides the QtSql module (that also supports SQLite natively) which has classes such as QSqlTableModel that can be used out of the box in item views such as QTableView. As long as you use related classes and functions, they can work seamlessly without the need to implement a layer between Qt and the sqlite module.

When it crashes, do you get any error message or traceback? (If there's no error message, in my experience, the issue is usually passing incorrect types to a QT method, which causes a segfault in the C (so no useful info).

@Kaia I get "Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)". I read into this but nothing seemed relevant or helpful, but I certainly could be wrong. Thanks!

@HansHinnershitz Yeah, not very informative. But It's helpful in that you know it's a a C-level crash, not a python-level one. That strongly suggests QT is involved in whatever's going wrong. I agree with Mike, your next step is making a self-contained example that's as small as possible but still crashes, and then finding the exact line(s) where if you remove it, it doesn't crash. Debugging QT can be a bit of a hassle. If you aren't using a python debugger already, the ability to set breakpoints might be very useful in debugging this.

@HansHinnershitz IDEs are not always capable of showing errors resulting from a binding library (which often outputs to the stderr) or displaying the full traceback. If you're running the script from the file manager, it's even more useless most of the times. The first thing you should do is to run the script in a terminal or prompt (which is something that should always be done in any case, even if the program works as expected in the IDE). That will probably show further debug info (and if it does, then [edit] your post and provide the full output), but that's not a certainty.

@HansHinnershitz The reason for that uncertainty is that, when using bindings, objects are normally "wrapped" with pointers to memory addresses that refer to the actual object of the "bound library" (Qt, in this case), which usually has no awareness about its being "managed" from Python. From its point of view, it's working as a standard C++ program. Therefore, the problem may be that some objects may be destroyed unexpectedly, which would be already a problem for a standard C++ program (but trackable with a related debugger), but can become much more difficult to resolve with a binding.

@musicamante Your comment about running through the terminal gave me an insightful error that led to a solution. Now I just need to figure out how to be able to filter on my sorts and sort on my filtered table without it being cleared each time. One thing at a time, lol. Thanks so much!
